# Express.js how to prevent request if another one is being handled?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

is there a way to prevent request if another one is being handled at the moment in express.js.
I have a code like this

```
 try {
    if (currency == 'BTC') {
      let options = {
        symbol: symbol,
        side: 'BUY',
        type: 'MARKET',
        quantity: amount,
        timestamp: Date.now()
      }

      let order = await api.placeOrder(options);
      if (order.status == 200) {
        res.status(200).send({ message: 'Order successfully placed' });
      } else {
        res.status(500).send({ message: 'Failed to place order' });
      }
    } else if (currency == 'DASH') {
      let options = {
        symbol: 'DASHUSDT',
        side: 'BUY',
        type: 'MARKET',
        quantity: amount,
        timestamp: Date.now()
      }

      let order = await api.placeOrder(options);

      if (order.status == 200) {
        res.status(200).send({ message: 'Order successfully placed' });
      } else {
        res.status(500).send({ message: 'Failed to place order' });
      }
    } else {
      res.status(400).send({ message: 'Invalid currency' });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send({ message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
```

Which basically allows users to buy bitcoin through the website, the problem is that sometimes one account can be used by more than two people and just in case if they will press buy button at the same time it would place orders twice. Is there a way to disallow other user to place an order if one is being processed at the moment?

Comment: Do you want to STOP the second request, or make the second request wait for the first one to be finished?

Comment: @TKoL stopping would be better

Comment: In either case, I would use a `try - catch - finally` clause -- the finally will run no matter way, so at the beginning of the `try` you use add a key, for example, that uniquely identifies the resource you're locking -- for example, if you're locking just this request for just this user, your key would be maybe `this_url:user_id` -- you set the lock at the beginning of the try, and you clear the lock in the `finally`, so that the lock gets cleared whether it errors or not.

Comment: Then, you make sure at the start of the request that you check the lock before you set it, and make the request fail if it's locked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a super crude example and it may not take into account all your needs, but... maybe it will?

```
const locks = {};

app.post('route', function(req, res) {
    const routeLockKey = 'route:' + user.id;
    if (locks[routeLockKey]) return res.error; // error here somewow

    // if we got here, the route isn't locked for this user
    locks[routeLockKey] = true;
    try {
        // your code here
    } catch(e) {
        // error handling here
    } finally {
        delete locks[routeLockKey];
    } 
    
});
```

Comment: I use a library in my own code for WAITING for locks to clear, rather than making the request error if it's locked. That library is the npm package `await-lock`

Comment: You could even make this into a middleware possibly...